# Database Mail connection to exchange - Resets and timeouts

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I am trying to send the results of a query in an email, and each time it takes longer than 5-10 minutes for me to recieve the message. The actual relay from Exchange takes less than one minute, but when I send larger emails (bigger than 200KB), Exchange doesn't even show that it recieved the email.

Wireshark reveals two issues on the client (SQL Server) side:

1. Database Mail is issuing RSET commands over and over again before sending any data. It takes several minutes before any actual DATA packets are sent.
2. After Database Mail has sent 14 DATA packets, Exchange immediately acknowledges the packets. Before Database Mail sends the next 14 packets, 10-30 seconds pass with no traffic.

Ultimately, this means that if I am trying to send an email larger than 200KB from SQL Server, I end up with a timeout from exchange after 5 minutes. Has anyone encountered this issue?

I have tried this on multiple machines, and using both SQL 2012 and 2008R2, getting the same results each time.

Comment: Check with your Exchange Admin. We have sql server 2008R2 and 2012 sending out emails with more than 200KB without any issues.

Comment: I have been working with the Admin, but we aren't seeing anything that suggests this is on the Exchange side. Exchange is responding to all the network traffic with no latency, but Database Mail is taking up to 30 seconds to resume sending the traffic. 14 DATA packets equal 20KB, and it only gets through about 11 of these sets before it hits the timeout.